# Can I be with the girl who had been in haram relationships before and kissed a guy?

Tags: nikah

Asalam alikum, I wanted to ask if it will be okay with norms of Islam that if I want to marry a girl and she has a bad past and people know about it should I be with her and marry her? I know a girl who wants to marry we have no haram relationship between us we talking to out parents but recently I found out she had many haram relationships and kissed some boys and I kinda don't like her anymore not because she had a bad history but the society and people know about her and I wanted to know what quran and hadiths say about this? And should I advance my relationship with her?

Answer (score 0):

If she truly repented and changed her way, living her life according to Islam. Wearing Islamic clothing, proper hijab, niqab. Then inshallah no problem as it's her past and we can't judge anyone for their past mistakes, especially if they repented, now it's between Allah and her. But if she didn't change her way then of course not. Look for pious and righteous sister. Inshallah Allah will help you